# mysql ERROR 1215 (HY000), what did i do wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql

i am working on a my database project for my class and i cant figure out why my ENROLL table is giving me the

> "ERROR 1215 (HY000):cannot add foreign key constrain"

im out of ideas, i already checked my book. any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE COURSE
(COURSE_ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
SUBJECT_ID INT(11) NOT NULL,
COURSE_GRADE_LEVEL CHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
FAC_ID INT NOT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY(FAC_ID) REFERENCES FACULTY(FAC_ID))

CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(STU_ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
STU_FNAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
STU_LNAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
STU_DOB VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
STU_STREET VARCHAR(150),
STU_CITY VARCHAR(50),
STU_STATE VARCHAR(3),
STU_ZIP VARCHAR(6),
STU_PHONE CHAR(12),
STU_GRADE_LEVEL CHAR(2) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE ENROLL
( COURSE_ID INT(11) NOT NULL ,
STU_ID INT(11) NOT NULL,
GRADE CHAR(3) NOT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY(COURSE_ID) REFERENCES COURSE(COURSE_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(STU_ID) REFERENCES STUDENT(STU_ID),
PRIMARY KEY (COURSE_ID,STU_ID));
```

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY(FAC_ID) REFERENCES FACULTY(FAC_ID))`  You are referencing table `FACULTY`, but have no table of that name listed, or created before that statement runs.

Comment: Can you post the CREATE for table FACULTY

Comment: I just realized my stupid mistake, i misspelled STUDENT, i wrote it as STUDNET. Thanks guys